# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This task has already been stopped'

Tags: ios, xcode

I am facing this exception when i upgrade my project from xcode 12 to 15. This issue happens only on header icons, My application is a hybrid application as it is working good in web and android but In IOS alone it causing exception.

Failed to request query parameters from WebPrivacy.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This task has already been stopped'

*** First throw call stack:

(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b52e28d __exceptionPreprocess + 242

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108d4f894 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b52e16b -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0

3   WebKit                              0x000000010eff76be -[WKURLSchemeTaskImpl didReceiveResponse:] + 141

4   Hybrid                              0x0000000107b1bcaa __41-[CustomUrlScheme executeRequestForTask:]_block_invoke + 666

5   CFNetwork                           0x000000010d31bda7 CFNetwork + 36263

6   CFNetwork                           0x000000010d339915 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 16951

7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbd3747 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbd49f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbdc8c9 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1127

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbdd665 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 441

11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbea76e _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 318

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbe9b69 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 590

13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010c183c55 _pthread_wqthread + 327

14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010c182bbf start_wqthread + 15
```

)

libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID

THREAD WARNING: ['GoOffline'] took '248.6589' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

warning: Module "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib" uses triple "x86_64-apple-macosx13.6.0", which is not compatible with the target triple "x86_64-apple-ios12.0.0-simulator". Enabling per-module Swift scratch context.Failed to request query parameters from WebPrivacy.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This task has already been stopped'

*** First throw call stack:

(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b52e28d __exceptionPreprocess + 242

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108d4f894 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b52e16b -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0

3   WebKit                              0x000000010eff76be -[WKURLSchemeTaskImpl didReceiveResponse:] + 141

4   Hybrid                              0x0000000107b1bcaa __41-[CustomUrlScheme executeRequestForTask:]_block_invoke + 666

5   CFNetwork                           0x000000010d31bda7 CFNetwork + 36263

6   CFNetwork                           0x000000010d339915 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 16951

7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbd3747 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbd49f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbdc8c9 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1127

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbdd665 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 441

11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbea76e _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 318

12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010bbe9b69 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 590

13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010c183c55 _pthread_wqthread + 327

14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010c182bbf start_wqthread + 15
```

)

libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID

THREAD WARNING: ['GoOffline'] took '248.6589' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

warning: Module "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib" uses triple "x86_64-apple-macosx13.6.0", which is not compatible with the target triple "x86_64-apple-ios12.0.0-simulator". Enabling per-module Swift scratch context.

Comment: I faced the same exception when upgrading a project from Xcode 14.3 to 15. However, touching the code and rerunning made the problem disappear. Maybe try a clean build? Or does the problem persist?

Comment: I have tried to do a clean build but the problem exists.